# violation of the terms of service

Tags: copyright, terms-of-service

literally i have an app(to earn money) that parses google.translate results. Changes it(info from google) and puts it in. And it seem I am violating terms of service because i am scraping google.translate site and getting information from it, but then i somehow changing it. But still i am a bad person. And google detected and proved that it was me and my app doing such unscrupulous action. 
What kind of punishment/penalty etc will apply to me?

Comment: Most likely they will pull your app from the app store, more egregious violations may result in you being permanently blocked as a developer/publisher. Its doubtful it would go beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At very least, Google can deny your App access to their translation service and API, so your App won't work anymore. At most, they could - depending on jurisdiction, i.e. where you are located - take you to civil court in California for damages. It's unlikely, but they could; but they could easily send you a threat letter which may require you to hire a lawyer to answer. From [Google Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en) *All claims arising out of or relating to these terms or the Services will be litigated exclusively in the federal or state courts of Santa Clara County, California, USA, and you and Google consent to personal jurisdiction in those courts.*

Comment: thank you for your answer very much ,it seems it is not felony? no crime?

Comment: It is a civil violation; there is a small chance it could be an actual crime in your jurisdiction.